# SQL Server: Insert Multiple Rows to a table based on a column in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cross-apply

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [StudentsByKindergarten]
(
    [FK_KindergartenId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentList] [nvarchar]
)
```

where the entries are

```
(1, "John, Alex, Sarah")
(2, "")
(3, "Jonny")
(4, "John, Alex")
```

I want to migrate this information to the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE [KindergartenStudents]
(
    [FK_KindergartenId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] [nvarchar] NOT NULL)
)
```

so that it will have

```
(1, "John")
(1, "Alex")
(1, "Sarah")
(3, "Jonny")
(4, "John")
(4, "Alex")
```

I think I can achieve split function using something like the answer here: [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Using the function here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str

I can do something like this,

```
INSERT INTO [KindergartenStudents] ([FK_KindergartenId], [Studentname])
    SELECT 
        sbk.FK_KindergartenId,
        parsed.txt_value
    FROM 
        [StudentsByKindergarten] sbk, dbo.fn_ParseText2Table(sbk.StudentList,',') parsed
GO
```

but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is a good reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: An example of using @wewesthemenace's link for a problem such as this is available at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72292/splitting-a-csv-column-from-select-query-into-multiple-columns/72298#72298

Comment: @Melissa, I've switched my old accepted answer by my new answer (using cross apply) that I believe is better for future readers. If you don't like the new answer, feel free to switch again the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817627/change-an-iterative-query-to-a-relational-set-query), I've learned a better approach for this problem. You just need to use `CROSS APPLY` with your suggested function [fn_ParseText2Table](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str).

[Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f738/1)

```
INSERT INTO KindergartenStudents
  (FK_KindergartenId, StudentName)
SELECT
  sbk.FK_KindergartenId,
  parsed.txt_value
FROM
  StudentsByKindergarten sbk
    CROSS APPLY
  fn_ParseText2Table(sbk.StudentList, ',') parsed
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the function that you suggested ([fn_ParseText2Table](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str)) and the following T-SQL is working. You can test it with this fiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16f96/5).

```sql
BEGIN
  DECLARE 
    @ID int, 
    @iterations int

  -- Iterate the number of not empty rows
  SET @iterations = 
        (SELECT 
          COUNT(*) 
        FROM
          StudentsByKindergarten
        WHERE
          DATALENGTH(StudentList) > 0
        )

  WHILE ( @iterations > 0 )

  BEGIN

    -- Select the ID of row_number() = @iteration
    SET @ID =
          (SELECT 
            FK_KindergartenId 
          FROM
            (SELECT 
              *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FK_KindergartenId DESC) as rn
            FROM 
              StudentsByKindergarten
            WHERE
              DATALENGTH(StudentList) > 0) rows
          WHERE
              rows.rn = @iterations
          )

    SET @iterations -= 1

    -- Insert the parsed values
    INSERT INTO KindergartenStudents
      (FK_KindergartenId, StudentName)
    SELECT
      @ID,
      parsed.txt_value
    FROM
      fn_ParseText2Table
    (
      (SELECT
        StudentList
      FROM
        StudentsByKindergarten
      WHERE
        FK_KindergartenId = @ID), 
    ',') parsed
    END
END
```